# Custom number formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a bit of code that is currently set to run a set of equations. I would like to allow the input of a custom numerical sequence. Instead of entering 100, I'd like to enter 1+00 but I'd like the code to interpret it as 100. After the equations are ran, I'd like the code to return results in the X+XX format.

I am new to coding (this is my first bit of code) and have looked around trying to find a way to format this. I know in excel I can specify custom number format of "#+##.00" to get it to output a cell in the format I require. I have been unable to find the python equivalent.

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def show_entry_fields():
     try:
          a, c, d, e, = float(e1.get()), float(e3.get()), float(e4.get()), float(e5.get())
          b = e - d
          s = (a + b + c) / 2
          height = (sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) * 2) / b
          height = float(format(height, '.3f'))
          height_label['text'] = str(height)
          side =((sqrt ((a ** 2) - (height ** 2))) + b)
          side = float(format(side, '.3f'))
          side_label['text'] = str(side)
     except ValueError:
          pass
     master.after(100, show_entry_fields)

master = Tk()
master.attributes("-topmost", True)
master.title("Triangulation Plotting")

Label(master, text="Measurement #1 Station Line Location").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e4 = Entry(master)
e4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Triangulation Measurement #1").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Measurement #2 Station Line Location").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e5 = Entry(master)
e5.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

Label(master, text="Triangulation Measurement #2").grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
e3 = Entry(master)
e3.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(master, text="Offset from station line").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
height_label = Label(master, text="")
height_label.grid(row=8, column=1)

Label(master, text="Measurement on Station Line").grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
side_label = Label(master, text="")
side_label.grid(row=9, column=1)

master.after(100,show_entry_fields)
master.mainloop()
```

Omitted sections are entry fields. The math and everything comes out exactly as needed. The entry of X+XX is the format that is used for the specific application this is intended. I looked in the str.format() under docs but did not see how I could do this.

EDIT:
So if I enter 2+66, it will be interpreted as 266. It will conduct the calculations based on the other inputs and the result will be shown in the same format. For numbers less than 100 or 1+00, it will output with a leading 0 i.e. 0+57 for 57. Entries and results will be in floating point. All results will be loaded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Please describe the *rules* for fomatting the numbers and give a few examples showing how different numbers are supposed to *appear*?

Comment: So if I enter 2+66, it will be interpreted as 266. It will conduct the calculations based on the other inputs and  the result will be shown in the same format. For numbers less than 100 or 1+00, it will output with a leading 0 i.e. 0+57 for 57.

Comment: Please include that in your question. - Integers only or floating point also?

Comment: Floating point. Will update the question.

Comment: What is 266.237 supposed to look like? and 2345.237?

Comment: 2+66.24 and 23+45.24

Comment: I'm a bit confused, all the examples in the question are integers and their string representation does not contain a decimal point or digits after it - yet you said everything is a float.

Comment: I provided integers for simplicity. Actual numbers I input are to one decimal place, but the math rounds to 2 decimal places. Basically, the code helps plot points in Microsoft Vizio when the measurements were obtained via triangulation. The code then tells the user the x measurement and the offset of x measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings, split on `'+'` and `'.'`, construct a number with an f-string; turn it into a float and round it.  For a float, round to required precision, turn into a string, split on `'.'` then construct with an f-string.

```
def convert(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, str):
        a,b = thing.split('+')
        b,*d = b.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = round(float(f'{a}{b}.{d}'), 2)
    elif isinstance(thing, (int,float)):
        thing = str(round(thing, 2))
        thing,*d = thing.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = thing if len(thing) > 2 else '0'+thing
        thing = f'{thing[:-2]}+{thing[-2:]}.{d}'
    return thing
```

Python 3.6 required for [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

For Python 3.5- use string formatting:

```
thing = round(float('{}{}.{}'.format(a,b,d)), 2)
# and
thing = '{}+{}.{}'.format(thing[:-2],thing[-2:],d)
```

---

Usage
Strings to numbers:

```
>>> convert('2+66')
266.0
>>> convert('0+22')
22.0
>>> convert('2+66') + convert('0+22')
288.0
>>> x = '223+56.666'
>>> convert(x)
22356.67
>>> y = '-54+22.33212'
>>> convert(y)
-5422.33
>>>
```

Numbers to strings

```
>>> convert(22)
'0+22.00'
>>> convert(23454.22123)
'234+54.22'
>>> convert(-56732)
'-567+32.00'
>>>
```

---

When converting to a string if you need or want to justify the text within a fixed width you can add that to the specification.

```
def convert(thing):
    ...
    elif isinstance(thing, (int,float)):
        thing = str(round(thing, 2))
        thing,*d = thing.split('.')
        d = '00' if not d else d[0]
        thing = thing if len(thing) > 2 else '0'+thing
        thing = f'{thing[:-2]}+{thing[-2:]}.{d}'
        thing = f'{thing:^20}'
    return thing
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try tomorrow when I get home from work.

Comment: I'm on 3.6.6 so I'll try the f-string.

Comment: Due to a combination of my being new to coding, my lack of sleep (worked 16 hours yesterday and am headed back to work now), and my lack of time to play with it for more than 20 minutes today, I am unable to get it to work. Having said that, I basically dropped it in. Could you guide me on making it function? Updated original question with entire code (not terribly long) prior to adding what you put.

Comment: Thank you @wwii, you have been a ton of help. One final question: How would I implement it to auto read the fields and convert similar to how I have the calculations happening automatically?

Comment: I am having trouble implementing it into reading the tkinter Entry field and printing on the tkinter Label field. I'm sure it's something easy and obvious, however, I am still having trouble. I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I thought the question was for translating custom number formats.  If you are having problems with a tkinter application/for *also*, you should ask another question specific to that problem. Please don't mutate questions to ask new questions, just ask a new question.